# How to get zookeper znode data with metadata

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I've zookeeper server in our production data center 1. When I do `get` on znode, I get below result:

```
$ usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181

Connecting to localhost:2181
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is enabled

WATCHER::
WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null

[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 1] get /ids/id
0
cZxid = 0x50000013f
ctime = Tue Feb 07 14:02:35 EST 2017
mZxid = 0x1500002b86
mtime = Thu May 14 11:04:08 EDT 2020
pZxid = 0x50000013f
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 22
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 52
numChildren = 0
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 2]
```

I did get on another zookeeper in data center 2.I get below result:

```
$ /usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181
/usr/bin/java
Connecting to localhost:2181
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is enabled

WATCHER::
WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null

[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 1] get /ids/id
1
```

As you can see there is no metadata for get request in data center2 zookeeper.
How can I enable the same?

Comment: Could you please include the ZooKeeper version number that you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `-s` flag for the `get` command to get metadata. So:

`get -s /ids/id`